# OpenGL stop drawing when moving window lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So basically i want to draw every time even when the window is moved because i'm using delta time to move animation and stuff. This mean if the opengl stop, the time is still going and sometimes it makes the player go through wall and blink to other place :/ how can this be fixed? i already try to use thread but it's not working (or at least i code it wrong)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just cap the deltaT if it gets too big. Or, if you have separate calls for rendering and movements (I'd recommend that anyway so you can drop rendering frames without having extremely large movements), and the deltaT gets too big, break it down to several smaller calls.

Capping:

```
public void update(int deltaMs) {
  if (deltaMs > 100) {
    deltaMs = 100;
  }
  ...
```

Split off rendering from updates and do small updates:

```
public void update(int deltaMs) {
   while(deltaMs > 100) {
      updateImpl(100);
      deltaMs -= 100;
   }
   updateImpl(deltaMs);
   render();
 }
```

You could even combine both approaches:

```
public void update(int deltaMs) {
   // Cap at one second.
   if (deltaMs > 1000) {
     delatMs = 1000;
   }

   // Handle movements in small steps to avoid going through walls etc.
   while(deltaMs > 100) {
      updateImpl(100);
      deltaMs -= 100;
   }
   updateImpl(deltaMs);

   render();
 }
```

Comment: i supposed capping the delta is easier than breaking render call aparts.. how do you actually do this capping?

Comment: I have sketched what the approaches roughly should look like in the answer above.

Comment: Hey thanks :D but doesn't breaking updates apart like that can make an infinite loop if we got let's say 8 fps because of major lag?

Comment: It is impossible that the loop runs for an infinite number of iterations as deltaMs is finite and we reduce the value with each iteration. That said, you may still get a huge lag if updateImpl is relatively slow (usually rendering is the slower part, though). So perhaps for single player games, the best solution might be to combine both approaches.

Comment: Wait.. what? what do you meant by combine both approaches?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly again